# Using Brainflow in UXF to write EEG timeseries data to a csv file in Unity. How should I save the data so that it can be later accessed by my project?

Tags: database, csv, unity-game-engine, recording, writefile

I save recordings of timeseries data using Unity Experimental Framework to a local folder within the project.
Previously using `Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Recordings", str_subject, "S" + str_session).Replace("\\", "/");`

However a certain AI recommended using `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Recordings", str_subject, "S" + str_session).Replace("\\", "/");`

The persistenDataPath makes it so that it saves my data to a file which can accessed later however when I print the save location its in a local file as apposed to within the project file (I don't want to write to user's local machines). So I believe I'm looking at the problem wrong, what is the best way to save timeseries data (preferably .csv) in a way that it can be accessed from the file without getting a permission error?

I've made sure to stop the connection prior to trying to access the file (and checked manually)

```
oboard_shim.stop_stream();
board_shim.release_session();
```